# Python 3.6 - Tensorflow DLL load failed when importing tensorflow

Tags: windows, tensorflow, python-3.6

I installed Tensorflow on my command prompt using pip3 on Python 3.6 using:

```
pip3 install tensorflow==1.5
```

When checking if I could import tensorflow off the terminal using Python I got the following error message:

```
Python 3.6.0rc2 (v3.6.0rc2:800a67f7806d, Dec 16 2016, 23:22:07) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

What exactly is missing from the DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any issues when installing? Also, why are you installing tensorflow 1.5 when 1.9 is available? I would first try `pip uninstall tensorflow` and then `pip install tensorflow`. If you still have issues I would try going [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow) to download the .whl file and then you can do `pip install [whatever the filename is].whl`. Directly installing these .whl files has solved many a problem for me.

To answer your question, it looks like you are missing descriptor.py from google protobuf. You could try downloading that and moving descriptor.py directly, but my guess is if it can't find one file it's probably missing other things as well.

Looking at other problems with tensorflow imports, it looks like the problem is compatibility with python 3.6 having a divergent path with pip, however it looks like this was solved at some point in the last year. If you're still stuck, of course try upgrading pip, python, and tensorflow; then try downgrading to python 3.5 to see if that works. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Change the protobuf version to pip install protobuf==3.6.0